# Moving Email Text to Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm looking to find a way to take a bunch of emails from Gmail with a specific label and format and place them into a Google Spreadsheet. All of these emails have exactly 15 lines and each line is separated into two parts by a colon. I found this script:

```
function getMessagesWithLabel() {
 var destArray = new Array();
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('FOLDER').getThreads(1,10);

  for(var n in threads){
        var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
        var destArrayRow = new Array();
        destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');
          for(var m in msg){
                     destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getSubject());
           }
  destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
        }
Logger.log(destArray);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
if(ss.getLastRow()==0){sh.getRange(1,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')};
sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray)
}
```

Which takes in the first 10 entries and returns the number of messages in the thread and the title. How can I modify a script like this to instead search each line for a colon and place the first half in Column 1 and the second half in Column 2 (to start for the first 10 entries)? Format example below.

```
A A: Data goes here
B B B B: Other data here
C C C: More data here
.
.
.
.
O O: Final line of data
```

Comment: Sorry new to apps script however to retrieve strings up to a colon you should use regex https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417

Comment: It will be something like    ^[a-z]+:

Comment: Each email may have 15 lines, but in what format? Plain text? HTML? Do you have an example?

Comment: @Mogsdad It's all text within the email itself, in plain text. Let me add an example of the format.